# Mesh in some places looks unsmooth and glitched

Tags: blender, mesh

So i'm modelling a face everything is great, then I look at the nose and boom. 
What is it? Why this mesh looks like I don't know... not smooth or separated.
How can I fix that?

Here's the image:
[nose problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLVB7.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. enter edit mode.
2. Right-click on your object
3. click "shade smooth"

If you are still not satisfied, try experimenting with some textures.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a hard edge on the normal, try highlighting everything in edit mode and mesh -> shade smooth

Comment: Also, there is a blender Stack Exchange. Can you ask this question there, rather than here?